# Using “one” with nouns whose countability is ambiguous

Tags: pronouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

An ESL student produced the following sentence:

“The Western diet seems to be more unhealthy than the Japanese one.”

The use of “one” immediately struck me as awkward, but not necessarily incorrect, as diet can be both countable and uncountable depending on the situation.

I corrected the sentence to, “The Western diet seems to be more unhealthy than that of Japan,” to avoid any confusion, but I honestly couldn’t decide if her version was actually grammatically incorrect or merely grossly awkward.

When using a strictly uncountable noun to make a similar sentence, such as, “The Western furniture was less stylish than the Japanese one,” it’s obvious that it’s incorrect.

However, when switching back to a noun that is both C and U, such as in, “The Western environment is less polluted than the Japanese one,” it becomes ambiguous again (to me anyway).

I realize that the best solution is to just fix the sentence as I did in the first example, but again, what I want to find an answer to is whether what she initially wrote is grammatically correct or not.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112168/discussion-on-question-by-tflo83-using-one-with-nouns-whose-countability-is-am).

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Your student is not wrong, and the correction is unnecessary.

The countability isn't exactly an issue, in this case the *one* is effectively acting as a pronoun (to avoid repeating the word *diet*).

Your correction, sadly, is wrong because the diet is of the *Japanese*, not *Japan*. You should finish it *… that of the Japanese* to be correct (and I fear it sounds more awkward - and somewhat academic in style - to boot).

To suggest that “her version” was “grossly” awkward I find offensive - it is no such thing.

*Western furniture* might almost be considered countable in a sense, but yes, that sentence is clearly wrong.

The environment is either a single thing (global), or a local condition, and as such every city, town, village, square foot, person and animal in the West has its own (local) environment - *The environment is less polluted in the West than in Japan* [but I'm not convinced of this, having seen some of both].

The best solution would be to admit you were wrong and apologise to her.

Comment: CW because I don't want points for this.

Comment: "One" _is_ a pro-form here, but it's _not_ a pronoun (there is a difference). It's actually a count noun.

Comment: @BillJ but the count isn't its purpose in that context, its purpose is a placeholder. So while *one* might not be *a pronoun*, it is most definitely being *used like one* here. Swan lists it last in section 14, *Pronouns*, as *"one (substitute word)"*.

Comment: That's why we have the term 'pro-form'. The pro-form "one" differs from a pronoun in that it takes determiners, such as "this" and "the". Additionally, it is like prototypical common nouns in having an inflectional contrast between singular "one" and plural "ones". (Btw, in my last comment I typed "count", when I should have typed "common").

Comment: I can't sanction your judgement here. I'd not rate 'The Western diet seems to be more unhealthy than the Japanese one.' as ungrammatical, but it loses half a mark for clumsiness if I'm doing the marking. 'The green car looks even older than the blue one.' is fine, with concrete referents.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know some of this is a little bit subjective, but that's why I felt the "correction" to be a bit too heavy-handed (and was somewhat harsh in my response). If they'd simply suggested it was "a little awkward" I might well have agreed! Although I'd probably write the sentence the same way as a native speaker, so I'm hardly going to bash it too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count diets... I'm on 'a diet'.. which diet are you on? is perfectly fine... it's not necessary to say which 'type of diet are you on?'... this can be used as a way to check.

I'm on a furniture. X

I'm in an environment = fine (context is important and providing it is the same context you could then use 'one' in the sentence you said)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).